# Extra Characters printed in the file

Tags: c, file-io, cryptography, garbage

I have made a program to encrypt and decrypt a message using a vigenere cipher.

While encrypting or decrypting the text, some extra garbage values are printed in it.

It takes the input from a file named `input.txt` and outputs to `output.txt`, you have to write the message in the `input.txt` file and  while running you have to give a key (a word with alphanumeric characters).

Why is this is happening?

The code is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>



int Encrypt(char key[])         // CODE FOR ENCRYPTION
{
    int sz = 0, i;
    FILE *ifp, *ofp;
    ifp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    char *buffer;
    char outputFilename[] = "output.txt";


    if (ifp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cant open input file\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    fseek(ifp, 0, SEEK_END);
    sz = ftell(ifp);

    // printf("%d",sz);

    fseek(ifp, 0, SEEK_SET);


    /* allocate memory for entire content */
    buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * sz);
    if (!buffer)
        fclose(ifp), fputs("memory alloc fails", stderr), exit(1);

    /* copy the file into the buffer */
    if (1 != fread(buffer, sz, 1, ifp))
        fclose(ifp), free(buffer), fputs("entire read fails", stderr), exit(1);


    ofp = fopen(outputFilename, "w");

    if (ofp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open output file !\n");
    }
    // fprintf(ofp,"%s",buffer);

    int j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); i++)
    {
        if (j > strlen(key) - 1)
            j = 0;
        if (buffer[i] >= 65 && buffer[i] < 91)
        {

            int c = ((((buffer[i] - 65) + ((key[j] - 65) % 26))) % 26) + 65;
            fprintf(ofp, "%c", c);

        }
        else if (buffer[i] >= 97 && buffer[i] < 123)
        {
            int c = ((((buffer[i] - 97) + ((key[j] - 65) % 26))) % 26) + 97;

            fprintf(ofp, "%c", toupper(c));

        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(ofp, "%c", buffer[i]);
            continue;
        }
        j++;
    }
    printf("\n");

    fclose(ifp);
    fclose(ofp);

    return 0;
}

int Decrypt(char key[])         // CODE FOR DECRYPTION
{

    int sz = 0, i;
    FILE *ifp, *ofp;
    ifp = fopen("output.txt", "r");
    char *buffer;
    char outputFilename[] = "output2.txt";


    if (ifp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cant open input file\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    fseek(ifp, 0, SEEK_END);
    sz = ftell(ifp);

    // printf("%d",sz);

    fseek(ifp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    /* allocate memory for entire content */
    buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * sz);
    if (!buffer)
        fclose(ifp), fputs("memory alloc fails", stderr), exit(1);

    /* copy the file into the buffer */
    if (1 != fread(buffer, sz, 1, ifp))
        fclose(ifp), free(buffer), fputs("entire read fails", stderr), exit(1);


    ofp = fopen(outputFilename, "w");

    if (ofp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open output file !\n");
    }
    // fprintf(ofp,"%s",buffer);

    int j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); i++)
    {
        if (j > strlen(key) - 1)
            j = 0;
        if (buffer[i] >= 65 && buffer[i] < 91)
        {
            if (buffer[i] > key[j])
            {
                int c =
                    ((((buffer[i] - 65) - ((key[j] - 65) % 26))) % 26) + 65;
                fprintf(ofp, "%c", tolower(c));
            }
            else
            {
                int c = ((((buffer[i] - key[j]) + 26)) % 26) + 65;
                fprintf(ofp, "%c", tolower(c));
            }
        }
        else if (buffer[i] >= 97 && buffer[i] < 123)
        {
            int c = ((((buffer[i] - 97) - ((key[j] - 65) % 26))) % 26) + 97;

            fprintf(ofp, "%c", tolower(c));

        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(ofp, "%c", buffer[i]);
            continue;
        }
        j++;
    }
    printf("\n");

    fclose(ifp);
    fclose(ofp);

    return 0;
}

void main()
{
    int ch;
    char key[20];
  a:printf("0.Exit the Menu\n1.Encrypt\n2.Decrypt\n");
    printf("Enter your choice\n");
    scanf("%d", &ch);


    switch (ch)
    {

    case 0:
        printf("Goodbye\n");
        break;

    case 1:
        printf
            ("-----------------------------Welcome to the encryption zone---------------------\n");
        printf("Enter the key to be used\n");
        scanf("%s", key);

        Encrypt(key);
        break;

    case 2:
        printf
            ("-----------------------------Welcome to the decryption zone---------------------\n");
        printf("Enter the key to be used\n");
        scanf("%s", key);

        Decrypt(key);
        break;

    default:
        printf("Enter the correct choice\n");
        goto a;
        break;

    }
}
```

Comment: shot-in-the-dark: did you forget to null-terminate?

Comment: Don't use `goto` in this case, use loops.

Comment: And you really should switch place of the second and third argument to `fread` and `fwrite`. The second is the size of each element and the third is the number of elements. You of course have to change the check of the return value as well.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are allocating and copying here

```
buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * sz);
if (!buffer)
    fclose(ifp), fputs("memory alloc fails", stderr), exit(1);   

/* copy the file into the buffer */ 
if (1 != fread(buffer, sz, 1, ifp))
    fclose(ifp), free(buffer), fputs("entire read fails", stderr), exit(1);
```

you've allocated `sz` bytes in buffer, and copied `sz` bytes, but you didn't leave room for the null terminator. Hence, when you check `strlen(buffer)` and encrypt later, you're going off into memory you didn't allocate.

To fix this, either you have to allocate one extra byte for the `'\0'`, or you copy over one less and tack on the `'\0'` at the end.

Comment: i found that the problem does not occur in ubuntu( gcc compiler) but it occurs when compiled in codeblocks on windows

Comment: The thing about that is that once you run off into unallocated memory, you instantly hit undefined behavior. Have you tried running your program through a memory-checker like `valgrind`? If it returns any memory errors, then it's not that you don't have a problem, it's that you're lucky and the undefined behavior happens to not involve a crash that one time.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong length calculation.

As mention by @Dennis Meng, the strlen(buffer) *likely* (*1) goes off past the end of your allocated buffer.  Your `malloc()` is fine.  The recommended solution is different.  Rather than tacking on a NUL char, change for 2 `for` loops

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); i++)
```

to

```
for (i = 0; i < sz; i++)
```

Not only will this fix the problem, it will run faster as you are no longer performing `strlen(buffer)` `sz` times.

*1 It would not go that far had your file contained a NUL character.  If it does go past the end of `buffer`, where things stop is UB.